# How to decrease indent in axis labels in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(project, aes(death_country))+
  geom_bar()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[The image is of plot I was trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bqie.png)

[image]

Comment: Change the last line to `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))`

Comment: Better: flip the plot horizontally and sort by `count` https://forcats.tidyverse.org/articles/forcats.html